# Elastic Beanstalk environments on console don't show on EB CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created an EB env on my AWS console and one on my local machine through `eb cli`. I have synced my AWS key pair and logged into my console through `eb cli` however the environment built through console does not show in terminal when I run `eb list`.

**This is what I see in terminal:**

> $ eb list
>
> - django-env

**This is what I see on my AWS console:**
[image]

Can someone shed some light on how to get the two connected?

Comment: what does `eb list --region us-east-2` return? By default, the EBCLI is associated with `us-west-2` for a lot of the operations.

Comment: @progfan I get `django-env`

Comment: Can you run `eb list --region us-east-2 --debug`? There should be a statement in the debug logs that looks like "Making API call (elasticbeanstalk, describe_applications)". Check if it is accurately making a call to "us-east-2", or if it is to some other region. Also, from the console, can you check in which region `django-env` is really defined?

Comment: It's also possible that the CLI is using a different AWS account. I'd try using the `--profile` flag. If that doesn't work, you should reach out on AWS forums.

Comment: @progfan thanks, I will try that and get back to you!